# SSRS Table - How to re-create a deleted column for RowGroup

Tags: reporting-services, grouping

When you add a row group in a report, Visual Studio automatically adds a "Row Group Column", at the left, that results in a cell that spans for all the rows that conform the group:
[(image)](http://screencast.com/t/uvkTSMBqv3y)

Most of the time I delete those columns, and place a title in the row-group header, like this:
[(image)](http://screencast.com/t/OAqSGEXRJ9zk)

But now I have found that I need that Row-Group Column back.

Is there a way to re-create it without having to redesign all my table again?

Comment: I think can not re-create a deleted column and re-create it's easier. or Undo your change press (ctrl + z).

Comment: Well, undo is not an option since I made a lot of modifications to the report table after deleting the column.